# CSS Font face not working

Tags: css, font-face

Hey Ya'll my CSS font face is not working, I have no idea why, it was working a few days ago...

Here is the CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TrajanProBold';
    src: url('trajanpro-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('trajanpro-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('trajanpro-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('trajanpro-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('trajanpro-bold-webfont.svg#TrajanProBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'TrajanProRegular';
    src: url('trajanpro-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('trajanpro-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('trajanpro-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('trajanpro-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('trajanpro-regular-webfont.svg#TrajanProRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}


body{
    font-family:TrajanProBold;
    background-color:#ebebeb;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

and this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.willruppelglass.com/css/slimbox2.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.willruppelglass.com/css/styles.css" />
```

Any Help would be appreciated,
J

Comment: maybe it's stupid suggestion, but try `font-family: 'TrajanProBold';`

Comment: There is no such thing as a stupid suggestion, but no i did not work :(

Comment: What browser are you using? what's the extension of your font?

Comment: Are you the owner of willruppelglass.com? If not, perhaps they are blocking you from linking to those files.

Comment: I am using Firefox 11 on Windows 7

Comment: fixed the problem by taking out http://www.willruppelglass.com out of my href attribute

Comment: Welcome to SO @user1274810.  If you fixed the problem, you should add the fix as an answer and then accept it, so that people know the question has been answered and so that people can reference the correct answer.

Comment: Try using chrome. I came across the same problem...turns out that Firefox has some issues and doesn't support certain fonts. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your stylesheet ( http://www.willruppelglass.com/css/styles.css ), I can see that the `TrajanProBold` is being applied to only two elements:

`body` and `input`

However, the Slimbox stylesheet ( http://www.willruppelglass.com/css/slimbox2.css ) has another font stack applied to

`#lbBottom`

So, the Slimbox fonts would override the `TrajanProBold` font, at least on the element mentioned.

Comment: how do you avoid font override?  Bootstrap and font awesome seem to work well together.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with custom fonts you need the '' so you should try it as 'TrajanProBold'. Hopefully its as simple as that.

Comment: Double check the location of the font. Are the font files in your CSS folder?

Comment: I checked out your website and I am seeing the Trajan font in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari on my MAC. What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Yup everything is where it should be...I noticed this issue when I installed jQuery slimbox, it came with its own CSS file

Comment: and now Firefox 11 on Windows 7

Comment: fixed the problem by taking out http://www.willruppelglass.com out of my href attribute

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
src: url('trajanpro-regular-webfont.eot');
```

to

```
src: url('trajanpro-regular-webfont.ttf');
```

Answer (score 0):

check your .htaccess in root folder as well in sub directories. 
Apply following code to appropriate .htaccess file.

```
Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    <Files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js|svg|woff|ttf|eot|woff2)$">
    Allow from all
    </Files>
```

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? Apache configuration is one possible cause of the issue.